# SceneKit & Swift: How to use SCN object as floor?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit

I have created a mountain landscape in Blender and imported it into my Xcode project.

https://github.com/QBeukelman/Mars_Curiosity.git

I would like to drive the SCNVehicle on the landscape as if it were the floor of the scene (landscapeMountains.scn).

The vehicle falls through the landscape!

I have tried the following to solve the issue, but without success:

1. Different combinations of static, kinetic and dynamic physics bodies.
2. Using different collision margins such as 0.01
3. Using category and collision masks (see image)

Does anyone know how to use a scn object as a floor using SceneKit and Xcode?

[category & collision bit masks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVVC0.png)

Comment: can you provide your project for download?

Comment: @ZAY - Working on it!

Comment: @ZAY The repo link is now available! (sorry for the delay). I am guessing that for the physics properties to work, you need to pass a shape property into the object. In this example I am using a SCNBox. How do I pass the shape of the mountainLandscape.scn into the shape property of the physics object? To use it as the floor in the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your entire "`// add mountain`" code block (line 185 to 191 in GameViewController.swift) with this:

```
func floorPhysBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType = .static, shape: SCNGeometry, scale: SCNVector3 = SCNVector3(1.0,1.0,1.0)) -> SCNPhysicsBody {
            
    // Create Physics Body and set Physics Properties
    let body = SCNPhysicsBody(type: type, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: shape, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron, SCNPhysicsShape.Option.scale: scale]))
        
    // Physics Config
    body.isAffectedByGravity = false
    return body
}
    
// configure Physics Floor
let mountain = scene!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "mountain", recursively: true)!
mountain.physicsBody = floorPhysBody(type: .static, shape: mountain.geometry!)
```

In addition: Your Mountain Geometry is very large (file is over 50MB in size for some geometry). I recommend you to reduce this, to avoid memory issues when your game grows. Also: try to avoid texture sizes bigger than 1024x1024. Use textures sizes from a power of 2 if possible - like 128px, 256px, 512px, 1024px squared.

Have fun with your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works with the "landscapeMountains.scn", but does not work for any other landscape. For example, I have tried it with "Olympus_Mons.scn", but the vehicle falls through the floor. Why is that?

Comment: The effective geometry-node you are looking for might be also one ore multiple childNodes of the Node you are mapping. try to enumerate/count the childNodes and use those to set the physics body.

Comment: It seems that I am able to apply the PhysicsBody to the ChildNode. However, using showPhysicsShapes, the PhysicsBody is a tiny spot at position (0, 0, 0), and does not cover the shape of the ChildNode. See the image added to the question, named: "Physics Body Floor".

Comment: you need to apply the geometry from a node (regardless if it is a child node) to the physicsbody of itself. I also remarked, that the showPhysicsShapes does not always display correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Help me to understand, what is the difference between landscapeMountain.scn and Olympus_Mons.scn?

Comment: can you provide both files - I can't tell you without having a look at them.

Comment: https://github.com/QBeukelman/Mars_Curiosity.git (Mars Curiosity/artAssets/Landscapes)

Comment: The difference between landscapeMountains.scn & Olympus_Mons.scn is that landscapeMountains has a scale of 1,1,1, whereas Olympus_Mons a scale of 800,800,800. Changing "scale: SCNVector3 = SCNVector3(1.0,1.0,1.0))" to the required size fixed the issue, hence the tiny spot mentioned above. Thanks for the help ZAY, really appreciated.

Comment: @Quentin: This is it! You can add "SCNPhysicsShape.Option.scale: SCNVector3(800, 800, 800)" to the options array of the Physics Body